# Search for text inside a tag using beautifulsoup and returning the text in the tag after it

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the follow **HTML** code in python using beautiful soup. I would like to be able to search for text inside a tag, for example "Color" and return the text next tag "Slate, mykonos" and do so for the next  tags so that for a give text category I can return it's corresponding information.

However, I'm finding it very difficult to find the right code to do this.

```
<h2>Details</h2>
<div class="section-inner">
    <div class="_UCu">
        <h3 class="_mEu">General</h3>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Color</span>
            <span class="_KDu">Slate, mykonos</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_UCu">
        <h3 class="_mEu">Carrying Case</h3>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Type</span>
            <span class="_KDu">Protective cover</span>
        </div>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Recommended Use</span>
            <span class="_KDu">For cell phone</span>
        </div>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Protection</span>
            <span class="_KDu">Impact protection</span>
        </div>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Cover Type</span>
            <span class="_KDu">Back cover</span>
        </div>
        <div class="_JDu">
            <span class="_IDu">Features</span>
            <span class="_KDu">Camera lens cutout, hard shell, rubberized, port cut-outs, raised edges</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use the following code to retrieve my div tag

```
soup.find_all("div", "_JDu")
```

Once I have retrieved the tag I can navigate inside it but I can't find the right code that will enable me to find the text inside one tag and return the text in the tag after it.

Any help would be really really appreciated as I'm new to python and I have hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to return the value for the key you enter:

```
def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=key).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text

color = get_txt(soup, 'Color')
print('Color: ' + color)
features = get_txt(soup, 'Features')
print('Features: ' + features)
```

Output:

```
Color: Slate, mykonos
Features: Camera lens cutout, hard shell, rubberized, port cut-outs, raised edges
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Explanation:**

`soup.find('span', text=key)` returns the `<span>` tag whose `text=key`.

`.parent` returns the parent tag of the current `<span>` tag.

Example:

When `key='Color'`, `soup.find('span', text=key).parent` will return

```
<div class="_JDu">
    <span class="_IDu">Color</span>
    <span class="_KDu">Slate, mykonos</span>
</div>
```

Now we've stored this in `key_tag`. Only thing left is getting the text of second `<span>`, which is what the line `key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text` does.

Comment: Yes it does ! Thank you ! Although I would like to understand why it works :) are you able to explain `def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=key).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text`

Comment: @AlexB, I've added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps understand what is actually going on.One more question if I may. How would you handle cases when the text is not present without having to delete the `get_txt` code? At the moment I can only delete otherwise my script obviously gives me an error if I'm parsing another page where the `get_txt` i've defined if not present.

Comment: You need to learn error handling for that. It becomes easier to handle such cases with [Try and Except in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except). Read this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go. It can also give you the corresponding values. Make sure to wrap the `html elements` within `content=""" """` variable between Triple Quotes to see how it works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for elem in soup.select("._JDu"):
    item = elem.select_one("span")
    if "Features" in item.text:  #try to see if it misses the corresponding values
        val = item.find_next("span").text
        print(val)
```

Comment: Try to input here `if "Features"` your search items (replacing the existing one) to get the corresponding one.

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you very much! If the item is not present it doesnt return an error which is exactly what I was looking for. However, when I try to use `val` with the csv module I do get an error if the item is not present:    'with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
 writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 writer.writerow(['val'])  >> NameError: name 'val' is not defined which makes sense but I was hoping it would just come up as empty instead of an error.