# How to use get_txt to match only part of text instead of exact text

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using `partnumber = get_txt(soup, 'Part Number')` however occasionally **Part Number** is in the plural **Part Numbers** which breaks my script. How can I get around this so that if the text **Part Number** is matched then I can `get_txt` ?

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(urldet, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
partnumber = get_txt(soup, 'Part Number')
```

and here is the error when

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  in get_txt
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=key).parent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

It makes sense that I get an error since the is no text **Part number** but instead, the text **Part numbers** so to solve it I manually change the text I'm looking for but I would like to avoid having to do it manually.

Comment: what is the value of `soup`?

Comment: the value of soup is an html page

Comment: maybe no "Part Numbers" exist in `soup`

Comment: What is get_txt? What error happens when your script breaks?

Comment: edited above with more details

Comment: You need to add the `get_txt` function in the question.

Comment: Also it'll be easier to answer if you provide the HTML required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use get_txt to match only part of text instead of exact text

The answer to this is [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

You can add regex search for text in your `get_txt` function.

```
def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(key)).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text
```

You can see that I've changed `text=key` to `text=re.compile(key)`. This will match `Part Number` with `Part Numbers` or any other text that has `Part Number` in it.

Comment: For others who are wondering where that `get_txt` function came from, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200341/search-for-text-inside-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-and-returning-the-text-in-the-t). I guess this is a continuation of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48200476/7832176) to that question.

Comment: Also, don't forget to `import re` for using regex.